# How to install GoCD-S3-Artifacts for GO server

Tags: amazon-s3, go-cd

I want to install S3 plugins for GO-CD into my GO server. I found "S3 artifacts poller" on http://www.go.cd/community/plugins.html, but the "Download" link leads to nothing about jar package.

Again the document states nothing about how you can download the jar neither. http://ind9.github.io/gocd-s3-artifacts/installation.html

Can anybody help me out how I can get the plugin jar package? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Jars are available under Github [Releases](https://github.com/ind9/gocd-s3-artifacts/releases) now.

Comment: I appreciate so much.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the author of the plugin hasn't provided the Jars. He has however provided the [instruction](https://github.com/ind9/gocd-s3-artifacts#build) to build one. I have [suggested](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/go-cd/CFOexPNHZB8/bm1IFUDt_aoJ) him to upload the jars on Github :)